# How to create a feature mask with a polygon?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, buffer, masking

I need to create the SAME polygon shape shown in the image below, just 2 miles larger.  The buffer wizard tool is only creating circular buffers around the irregular shape below.  Any ideas on how to preserve the shape just 2 miles larger?

[image]

Comment: I'm not sure I understand "2 miles larger". That implies a relative distance. If you offset or buffer the existing shape out that far, some of the smaller pro/intrusions are just going to disappear because they'll be swallowed up by other lines. If you wanted to keep that exact shape, you could *scale* it up, but that's a fixed ratio - 2x or 4x for example. If you had a distance now (say center to one edge), that was 100 ft and you wanted that to be 2 miles you could do the math to get a scale factor (5280 ft/mi), but "2 miles larger" doesn't really make sense.

Comment: What license level of arcGIS do you have?  If you have the Advanced level, you can change the line end type to Flat in the Buffer tool.

Comment: The Flat end won't help.  If you are using a projected coordinate system and not a geographic coordinate system, you can convert the polygon to a line and use the tool at:  http://www.arcgis.com/home/item.html?id=54ad502f798c4cc780a1132ad44670a9  The tool keeps sharp corners.  I believe you would keep the Right side line to form the expanded buffer.  You may have to close the end.  You can select the line you want to convert to polygons, then use the Construct Polygons button on the Topology toolbar (ArcGIS 10.0 or earlier) or the Advanced Editing toolbar (ArcGIS 10.1 or later).

Comment: Is this a one time deal; or you need a repeatable process?

Answer (score 0):

Sounds very much like you want scale the polygon rather than buffer it. As it appears to be a one off I would suggest you try using the Scale tool. It's one of those tools that is not added to the tool bar by default so no one ever knows about it.

Have a look at this [page](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#/Scaling_a_feature/01m800000026000000/) for guidance on using it.

Comment: Scale works 'well' if shape = it's convex hull. Otherwise copy parallel produces something closer to what @ZachS men

Comment: @FelixIP I think you have that backwards. Scale is the only way to preserve the shape of a concave hull. If you copy parallel or offset (which would first require breaking it into individual line segments), by the time you reconnect the offset segments again you'll eliminate the concave sections. On a convex hull, it would work either way.